# basemap Invalid RGBA argument

Tags: matplotlib

i have met problem when i want to add color to the map...This is the code

```
colors={}
statenames = []
cmap = plt.cm.YlOrRd
vmax = 68
vmin = 36
for shapedict in m.states_info:
    statename= shape_dict['NAME']
    statenames.append(statename)
    happiness= area['happiness']
    colors[statename] = cmap(np.sqrt((happiness- vmin) / (vmax - vmin)))[:3]

ax = plt.gca()
for nshape, seg in enumerate(m.states):
    color = rgb2hex(colors[statenames[nshape]])
    poly = Polygon(seg, facecolor=color, edgecolor=color)
    ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

and the ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: array([[ 0.87733948,  0.09316417,  0.11318724,  1.        ]...
thanks for help!!!

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. The problem seems to be independent on Basemap and your real data.

Comment: Here, `area['happiness']` seems to be a list or array or what ever else (how are we supposed to know?), but not a single number. Hence the cmap returns an array of several colors, while it seems you want to have a single color for each polygon.